# Partial derivative for mean absolute error

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient, gradient-descent, derivative

What is the partial derivative for MAE? I understand that for mean squared error (MSE) the partial derivative with respect to some `x1`  would be `-x1 * (y_pred - y_actual)` assuming the the following version of MSE is used.

[image: ML MSE function]

What is the partial derivative for `x1` when the loss function is MAE instead of MSE? I've been trying to find this but I haven't had any luck. Would it just be `-(y_pred - y_actual)` when `x1` is greater than 0, and `(y_pred - y_actual)` when `x1` is less than 0? Or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're having a single neuron, there's no fixed formula for partial derivative of loss function with respect to each weight; it depends strictly on the connections between neurons in the network. And the partial derivative formula is not only one, each weight has a different one.

For small network with kinda 2, 3 layers, apply chain rule, and sum rule to find the partial derivative of loss function manually, otherwise, dynamic programming in backpropagation is needed.